# Doxygen template for cell phones?

Tags: html, doxygen

Does anybody know of a mobile-phone-friendly template for Doxygen? I would like to convert the reference documentation of various libraries (http://manuals.garciaripoll.com) to a format that can be read on a smartphone.

This would also solve Google's complains about those webpages right now, which makes searching in them no longer possible, as Google bans non-mobile-phone-friendly pages.